# Compute a 95% confidence interval for the mean increase

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I'm asked to compute a 95% confidence interval for the mean increase in Y when x1 increases by one unit. Can someone help me out with this? It is for multiple linear regression. Would I just find a 95% confidence interval for $\beta_1$ ?

Comment: Probably yes, if everything else stays the same

Comment: So, it doesn't matter that it says x1 increases by one unit? Do I have to add that somewhere?